# Simple PHP Form Redirect

Tags: php, forms, post, redirect

I do a few websites for clients using either Indexhibit or Wordpress. I keep getting the same 'where do I login?' email from them so want to create a simple forward form on my site where a client can enter there URL, select either Wordpress/Indexhibit and click go and be forwarded on to there site.

I have constructed the following after some googling:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') : $siteid1 = $_POST['siteid1'];             header('Location: http://' . $siteid1 . '/ndxz-studio/'); else:?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['../PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<h3>Indexhibit</h3>
<p class='formp'>If your website is powered by <em>Indexhibit</em> submit your URL to be forwarded to your admin area</p>
<input  input class='loginforms' type="text"  value='i.e. your-domain-name.com' onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'i.e. your-domain-name.com':this.value;"   name="siteid1" />
<input class="btn btn-success loginbuttons" type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And then the same again directly beneath it for Wordpress.

However because I am using

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') : $siteid1 = $_POST['siteid1'];             header('Location: http://' . $siteid1 . '/ndxz-studio/'); else:?>
```

It only seems to take accept one form on the site. (so either indexhibit fails to go to /ndxz-studio or wp fails to go to wp-admin)

PHP is not my forte so apologies I have committed any stupid mistakes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of this:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') : $siteid1 = $_POST['siteid1'];
```

this is always true in your form. So, PHP executes it. PHP never reaches the second `if` statement, so it never executes.

Try an `if else` statement and make sure your form names are unique

EDIT:

here is some sample code to get you started.

```
if($_POST['siteid1']) {
    $siteid1 = $_POST['siteid1']; 
    // execute code here
} elseif($_POST['siteid2']) {
    $siteid1 = $_POST['siteid1'];
    // Execute code here
}
```

Comment: This is what I am struggling with. How do i construct the IF statement if the forms are separate?

Comment: See the sample above. Basically you're detecting which `$_POST` is set. Based off of that, you'll execute the appropriate code.

Comment: Here is a link to the docs for further clarification... http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: Cheers - I am thinking a radio button choice is the way to go rather than two separate forms. Will post completed code once I am done